# Python MySQLdb type error while using execute with %s

Tags: python, cursor, mysql-python, execute

I've started with a simple mysql query in python, returning all the columns of the table.
For some reason this command works:

```
cursor.execute("SHOW columns from students")
```

While all of the following return a type error:

```
cursor.execute("SHOW columns from %s", 'students')

cursor.execute("SHOW columns from %s", ('students',))

cursor.execute("SHOW columns from %s", ['students'])

cursor.execute("""SHOW columns from %s""", 'students')
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#60>", line 1, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SHOW columns from %s", 'students')
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 187, in   execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Please advise

Comment: The second form should work. Can you confirm what the error message is for the second form specifically? The example only shows the error for the first form.

Comment: Did you try `cursor.execute("SHOW columns from (%s)", ['students'])`?

Comment: the error from the 2nd one:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SHOW columns from %s", ('students',))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students'' at line 1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using format which is a recommended way to format strings:

```
cursor.execute("SHOW columns from {}".format('students'))
```

Comment: probably because in my case there's only argument, whereas in yours there're 2 and the 2nd one is treated as the 2nd argument passed to cursor.execute()

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("SHOW columns from VALUES (%s)", ('students',))
```

If you have too many variables you may want to break:

```
sql = "SHOW columns from VALUES (%s)"
values = ('students', 'teachers')
cursor.execute (sql, values)
```

But if you create a tuple ahead, as on:

```
sql = "SHOW columns from VALUES (%s)",('students', 'teachers')
```

You will need:

```
cursor.execute (sql[0], sql[1])
```